# My EC2 instances keep becoming inaccessible?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I had a set of t2.micro instances behind a load balancer that keep dying. By dying I mean the REST API running on them would stop responding and I couldn't SSH to the instances. I would have to launch new instances from a saved AMI.

I decided there must be something wrong with the AMI, so I rebuilt the server, got everything running and created a new AMI.

After about a week, the same problem is back. The basic monitoring shows little to no activity on the servers.

[image: EC2 instance performance]

The System Log on the instance shows that the server is starting fine and my nodejs REST API is being launched.

Has anyone else experienced this and been able to find a solution?